# Custom Cell Segue Sending Data to Second View Controller Not Working

Tags: swift, segue

I have a custom cell that I am using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to display.  It is populated by a plist file.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("challengeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChallengeCell
    // set labels
    cell.ChallengeLabel.text = challengeLevels[indexPath.row].uppercaseString
    cell.ChallengeMaxPoints.text = "Score: " + challengeMaxScore[indexPath.row]
    cell.SizeLabel.text = "Size: " + challengeSize[indexPath.row]
    // set color
    cell.ChallengeLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.ChallengeMaxPoints.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.SizeLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return challengeLevels.count
}
```

I am working on getting this to segue properly based on all of the guides that I've found here and elsewhere:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    challengeSelected = indexPath.row
    print("Send selected \(challengeSelected)")

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ChallengeSelected", sender: challengeSelected);
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ChallengeSelected") {
        if let nextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as? LevelListViewController)
        {
            print(challengeSelected)
            nextViewController.selectedChallenge = challengeSelected
        }
    }
}
```

The associated variable is assigned above in this class ChallengeListViewController as per the below:

```
var challengeSelected: Int = 0
```

The code doesn't error out, but it also doesn't send the value.  The corresponding ViewController list as per the below:

```
class LevelListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var selectedChallenge: Int = 0
    let getLevels = LevelList(challengeNumber: 1)
    var puzzleLevels: [String] = []
    var solvedStatus: [String] = []

    // UITableViewDataSource for Table
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print ("Receive Selected: \(selectedChallenge)")
        //Initalize Arrays
        var x = 0
        for _ in getLevels.levels {
            puzzleLevels.append(getLevels.levels[x][0] as! String)
            x = x + 1
            }

            //print (puzzleLevels.count)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    //How to create a table
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("levelListCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LevelListCell

        // set labels
        cell.levelNameLabel.text = puzzleLevels[indexPath.row].uppercaseString
        cell.levelStatusLabel.text = "Not Solved"

        // set color
        cell.levelNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.levelStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return puzzleLevels.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("selected \(indexPath.row)")
    }

}
```

Edit:

Screen shots of segues follows below:

[Segue Screen Shot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4T1Y.png)
[Segue Screen Shot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTKHB.png)

Help is **really** appreciated.  I am stumped.

Thank you,

Rich

Comment: Is challengeSelected getting printed?

Comment: Yes.  Send selected is 3 and received is 0.  It's like the segue gets called prior to the click and then never gets called again.  Sample output below. 0
Receive Selected: 0
Send selected 3
3
2016-08-29 17:16:44.517 Word Master[22766:822280] <UIView: 0x7f9c4a634810; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; tintColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9c4a634b90>>'s window is not equal to <Word_Master.LevelListViewController: 0x7f9c4c033770>'s view's window!

Comment: "Send selected \(challengeSelected)" should be the first line printed. Do you have a segue in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I have a segue called ChallengeSelected that goes from the customcell with class ChallengeCell to the other view controller LevelListViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When performing a segue within your code, take care not to also have a segue set up in your storyboard from the cell itself. The segue needs to be created from the view controller. Otherwise, when the cell is selected, the segue is occurring without giving your code the proper chance to run its course.

Delete the current segue in storyboard. Then CTRL-drag **from the viewController** (not the cell) to `LevelListViewController` and name it "ChallengeSelected". Now, when you select a cell, the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` will fire first and will call `performSegueWithIdentifier()`

[image]

**Edit:**

If all you're looking to do in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` is get the row that performed the segue, you can maintain your original setup of having the cell segue from the storyboard, remove `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` and in `prepareForSegue()` do:

```
challengeSelected = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
nextViewController.selectedChallenge = challengeSelected
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That fixed it.  I had been trying to get that to work for two days.

Comment: @Apocal Sure thing